# How to get my branch as default in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I go to run the pipeline it is bringing Master as default how to make it automatically grab my desired branch?

I want it to come loaded with the feat-regression-test branch:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops#set-a-new-default-branch

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops#set-a-new-default-branch

> 1 Under your project repo, select Branches.
> 2 On the Branches page, select More options next to the new default branch you want, and choose Set as default branch.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/media/pull-requests/set-default-branch-in-product.png]